# Editar campo a partir de una fecha en SQL Developer (DB2)

Tags: sql, date

Necesito actualizar el valor de un campo por otro a partir de una fecha determinada (`5/04/2017`). Se trata de una base de datos tipo DB2.

Estoy utilizando esta sentencia:

```
UPDATE tabla SET campo='valor_nuevo'
FROM tabla
WHERE (campo='valor_viejo' AND fecha>=DATE('2017-04-05'));
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> Informe de error:
> Error SQL: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLERRMC: =;IVIDAD.ACT_GEOGRAFIA;)
> ```

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: No pones que motor de base de datos estas usando, pero esa query es incorrecta, no puedes hacer `UPDATE...FROM`. Explica mejor que tablas están involucradas, pero si solo es una, lo logico es que la consulta fuera algo asi como : `UPDATE ARIADNA.ARD_RTC_STG_ACTIVIDAD SET campo='valor_nuevo'

WHERE (campo='valor_viejo' AND fecha>=DATE('2017-04-05'));`

Comment: Como bien dice el compañero No pueds usar el FROM en una sentencia UPATE. Aquí tienes la documentación de DB2 para esa sentencia: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/sqlp/rbafyupdate.htm

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/db2z_n.html 104 Token ilegal en el comando SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clausula `UPDATE` tiene este formato:

```
UPDATE tabla
SET columna1 = valor1, columna2 = valor2, ...
WHERE condición;
```

Con lo que tu query debería ser algo asi:

```
UPDATE ARIADNA.ARD_RTC_STG_ACTIVIDAD 
SET campo='valor_nuevo' 
WHERE (campo='valor_viejo' AND fecha>=DATE('2017-04-05'));
```

Esto suponiendo que solo hay una tabla involucrada. Si lo que quieres es actualizar datos de una tabla con datos de otra, la cosa puede ser diferente. Si es asi,edita tu pregunta y amplia la información.